# Is there a way to use Google Visualization API in java

Tags: android

I'm creating interactive charts in java for android environment.
Google visualisation API is very impressive.
I need to know how to use it in java. Is there any Wrapper API available for this?
Or Can I use it directly in my application. Can anyone post a code snippet for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/). You are still running JavaScript compiled from Java (see GWT for more details) but all your code is in Java.

Beware that not all visualizations are available as GWT widgets yet - see if *'GWT Integrated'* is present [here](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try [google-visualization-java](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-java/).  It has [full documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/dev/dsl_about.html), including [simple examples](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/dev/dsl_get_started.html).

Comment: FYI it is now https://github.com/google/google-visualization-java and last commit is from 2012 :/

Anything more recent?